# Aws passing credentials to ansible s3 module

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

In ansible,When I am passing the access key,secret key,token to my aws credentials,it  passes the access key to my ansible module s3 ,but when I am passing secret key and token it shows me `""VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER"`
like that.So how can I solve this.

In accesskey id there is no extra special symbols at all,we have only text alphabets,but in security ans session we have / and special symbols,may be due that it passes like `"VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER"`???

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5):

`aws_secret_key` and `security_token` are marked as `no_log` arguments. See [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py#L125).
It is sensitive data, so not printed to stdout and you see `VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER`.

If you absolutely need to get secret values printed to stdout, use `ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_ARGS_TO_STDOUT=1` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks,I tried in ansible config file,but still it shows same error,VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER while passing token and keys.

Comment: You can't avoid this text. But if you set `display_args_to_stdout`, the task header will change and look like this `TASK [ec2_remote_facts aws_secret_key=SSKDFBHJLSHB]`, so you can see the values.

Comment: i set display_args_to_stdout=true ,but whats  that TASK [ec2_remote_facts aws_secret_key=SSKDFBHJLSHB].Will i pass this to my s3 module,for accessing those token and keys????

Comment: I use ec2_remote_facts  - name: Gather EC2 facts.
  ec2_remote_facts:
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ session_token }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
  register: ec2_facts                                                                                                                i use like above ,still iam sseing a value passing like "no log param"

Comment: Sorry, I miss the point. If you question is not about why your secrets are not displayed, please rephrase your question to be more specific and accurate. Add sample playbook snippet if needed.